# SQL Server UPDATE SET CASE error

Tags: sql-server

```
UPDATE importing.table 
SET SheetName = CASE  
                   WHEN SheetName= 'balance_currency' 
                      THEN 'TY_balance_currency'
                   WHEN SheetName = 'rate_code' 
                      THEN 'TY_rate_code'
                END
```

When I run this code twice, the entire column `SheetName` becomes null, other than the specified `SheetName`s in this code. How do I prevent this from happening when I just want to update the specified `SheetName`s in this code?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have other value of sheetname other than those 2 that you specified in the case statement. So other than those 2 value, it is set as NULL

if you only wish to change those 2 then you can either add a WHERE clause

```
UPDATE importing.table 
SET SheetName = CASE  
                WHEN SheetName= 'balance_currency' THEN 'TY_balance_currency'
                WHEN SheetName = 'rate_code' THEN 'TY_rate_code'
                END
WHERE SheetName in ('balance_currency', 'rate_code')
```

OR add a `ELSE`

```
UPDATE importing.table 
SET SheetName = CASE  
                WHEN SheetName= 'balance_currency' THEN 'TY_balance_currency'
                WHEN SheetName = 'rate_code' THEN 'TY_rate_code'
                ELSE SheetName
                END
```

Note : option 1 is more efficient as it only updates those rows that you required and not affecting others

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Replace` for your requirement.

```
UPDATE importing.table
set SheetName = replace(replace(SheetName,'balance_currency','TY_balance_currency'),'rate_code','TY_rate_code')
```